# Defragment disk using Ubuntu

Tags: disk

Is it possible to defragment my disk to make more space using Ubuntu?

I searched for tools but I'm not sure which is recommended for this task.

Which is the best way to defragment my complete disk using Ubuntu?

Comment: Defragmentation does not free up space. Linux filesystems do not need to be defragmented. So, what are you trying to do? Which filesystem do you want to operate on?

Answer (score 4):

Defragmenting disks does not save space, it just reorganises the blocks of data in your files so they can be read faster. It was/is a big problem on file systems used by Windows, but is much less of an issue on filesystems that are (typically) used on Ubuntu installs. I've run linux bases systems for 18 years and never had to do it!

Suggest you use "Disk usage analyser" app to find what's eaten your space up. Also, if you've had the machine for a long time, try this at a terminal:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

This will remove packages that don't need to be there any more. Ubuntu is terrible at not removing old kernels that you don't need any more and this has been known to completely fill up disks.

You might also try `sudo apt clean` which will remove the .deb packages that your packages were installed from.

And of course, check your Recycle Bin!

Hope this helps.